# JSF inputFile action called whenever some button is pressed

Tags: java, xhtml, jsf-2.2

I have a following situation. Image upload works fine. But when I click "Delete image" button, nothing happens. Actually, the uploadEventFile method is called (and I get the error message from that method - no file selected), but the deleteEventImage method is never invoked. I tried adding one more test button and a test method, but the same thing happens - when I click the test button, the uploadEventFile method starts, I get the error message, and there is no "DEBUG ::: TEST" printed.
If I remove the file upload part (h:inputFile and corresponding h:commandButton), everything works fine, both the "Delete" and the "Test" button.
I think the problem is that the file upload method is called every time I click any button on the page, but I have no idea how to fix that.

**UploadForm.XHTML:**

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
 ...
 <h:inputFile label="file" value="#{imageUploadBean.part}" required="true" requiredMessage="File not selected!"/>
 <h:commandButton action="#{imageUploadBean.uploadEventFile}" value="Upload image">
  <f:param name="eventId" value="#{eventBean.editingEvent.id}"/>
 </h:commandButton>
 <h:commandButton action="#{eventBean.deleteEventImage}" value="Delete image"/>
 <h:commandButton action="#{eventBean.testAction}" value="Test"/>
 ...
</h:form>
```

**ImageUploadBean.java:**

```
public String uploadEventFile() {
   System.out.println("DEBUG ::: UPLOAD");
   /*...*/
   return null;
}
```

**EventBean.java:**

```
public String deleteEventImage() {
   System.out.println("DEBUG ::: DELETE");
   /*...*/
   return null;
}

public String testAction(){
   System.out.println("DEBUG ::: TEST");
   /*...*/
   return null;
}
```

**Edit:** The problem goes away if I change the h:inputFile's "required" attribute to false. The only thing I need to do after that would be to change the uploadEventFile method so it would check if there is a file specified. But I would like to know is there any way to solve the problem without changing the "required" attribute?

Comment: Try adding immediate="true" attribute to the Delete button.

Comment: you can also try putting file upload component in a separate form by itself.